# Dax Measure to count weekly series

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a simple SUM measure that shows me how often a service was booked for the corresponding week:

```
Service - WK48 - WK49
A       -  1   -   2
B       -  1   -   0
```

Now I would like to determine, how many weekly series were booked for the corresponding service.
That means, if a service was booked for 3 weeks in a row, that would be 1 series. The same goes for 1 week.

How would you calculate this?

The root table as a structure like:
Date - Service

Each row/ entry provides a booking.

Comment: Is three weeks in a row booked as one entry or three?

Comment: It should be booked / calculated as 1

Comment: No ideas? I am grateful for very help! @Alexis Olson

Comment: Count the rows from the service table maybe. It's hard to say without knowing what your tables look like.